# Can you make Windows 10 auto-login one specific user?

Tags: windows-10, auto-login

On my Windows 10 machine I have two users. One (A) has no password and one (B) has one.
I want Windows to automatically log in user A on startup.

It works when that user was the last one to log in. But when user B was the last one, the login screen for B shows up and i have to switch to the other.

Can I prevent that and auto-login A?

Comment: Two methods listed here: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html with a little more detail that what @Bilo specified below at the moment I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Type `control userpasswords2` in command prompt and there will be a GUI for you to configurate auto logon for specify user